# jQuery: hide a div when scrolling up or down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found a post on stack overflow similar to my issue and it only fixed half of my issue. I'm trying to figure how to hide a certain div when you scroll up or down from it. This is what I got so far, this piece of code only hides the div when I scroll up but how would I make it work both ways (scrolling up or down)?

```
var $toTop = $('#test');
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 850) {
        $toTop.SlideUp(); /* had to make a typo " $toTop.SlideUp();" to get it to work when scrolling up */
    } else if ($toTop.is(':visible')) {
        $toTop.slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: The better bind here would be to use .on('scroll') Not saying it will fix your problem.

Comment: I commented on the wrong thing below.  But why do you have the .is(':visible') here?  Is your intention to unhide it while you're scrolling up?

Comment: hide the div when scrolling up or down is the main purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Countering `slideUp()`, you have `slideDown()`!

```
var $toTop = $('#test');
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 850) {
    $toTop.slideUp();
}
```

Comment: It didn't work but to be fair I didn't explained in detailed. I have a hidden div, when a user clicks on a certain button it shows the hidden div. When I scroll up or down I want to re-hide that div that was hidden before

Comment: In that case, the first if in your example, without the typo, should just work. It'll slide the div back up after 850 pixels are scrolled down. What happens when you do that? Without the typo?

Comment: it works but every second time I click the button to show the hidden div it quickly shows the  hidden div and quickly hides it again without me scrolling up or down. (I hope that made sense)

Comment: Can you edit your original question with the hiding code, possibly the HTML of the button and how the button and div are positioned? (absolute, fixed etc) and comment here when you're done, I'll look further into it. If you can replicate it on jsfiddle, even better!

Comment: I'll create a jsfiddle file but it might take awhile

Comment: ok just what I thought it didn't work but heres the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2moyru20/ http://jsfiddle.net/2moyru20/embedded/result/

Comment: it works but its having the same issue where every second time i click on the button it will quickly show the hidden div and quickly hides it again.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to slide down/up? If it doesn't matter try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 850) {
        ('#yourdiv').addClass('hide');
    } else {
        ('#yourdiv').removeClass('hide');
    }
})
```

And add this to your css:

```
.hide {
    display:none;
    transition: .3s /* if you want it to fade out */
}
```

Comment: Is he scrolling past 850...Think of screen size.

Comment: Like @AndrewIce is saying, try changing 850 to 100 or something?